# Some Values are missing in the cells in google spread sheet when fetching the data from MYSQL Database using google app script

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc, google-sheets

Please help in this

Some Values are missing in the cells in google spread sheet when fetching the data from MYSQL Database using google app script. 
When I checked the same in Mysql Workbench, in that is shows the value.

```
function myMySQLFetchDataMS() { 


  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var start = new Date(); // Get script starting time

  var date1 = "'%Y-%m-01'";

  var event = "'%Event%'";
  var selfserve = "'%Self Serve%'";
  var Bidding="'%Bidding%'";
  var Filler="'%Filler%'";

  var query = 'SELECT *from campaigns';//added missing closing single quote and spelled campaigns properly by Cooper
    var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)

   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MS");
if (doc != null) {


  var range = doc.getRange("A:F");
  range.clearContent();

  Logger.log(doc.getIndex());
}

  // Returns the currently active spreadsheet
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
  var row = 0;
  var getCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); // Mysql table column name count.

  for (var i = 0; i < getCount; i++){  
     cell.offset(row, i).setValue(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1)); // Mysql table column name will be fetch and added in spreadsheet.
  }  

  var row = 1; 
  while (rs.next()) {
    for (var col = 0; col < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); col++) { 
      cell.offset(row, col).setValue(rs.getString(col + 1)); // Mysql table column data will be fetch and added in spreadsheet.
    }
    row++;
  }

  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  var end = new Date(); // Get script ending time
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: ' + (end.getTime() - start.getTime())); // To generate script log. To view log click on View -> Logs.
}
```

Google Spread sheet cell screenshot[image]

Mysql Workbench cell screenshot[image]

Screenshot with title
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNpMS.png)

Comment: Can you share a sanitised copy of your sheet?

Comment: Try `getFloat()` or some other type instead of `getString`

Comment: @RafaGuillermo - I didn't get you?
You want Google spread sheet copy with code?

Comment: @TheMaster - But how will it fetch the String values?

Comment: Doesn't look like strings there. Aren't they all numbers?

Comment: @TheMaster - Sorry, It also contains string column.

Comment: Can you fix the missing single quote in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing:

this `var range = doc.getRange("A:F");` to this `var range = doc.getRange(1,1,doc.getLastRow(),6);`

Comment: Tested your recommended change, but still not working.